# BigQuery - Execute SQL query generated from SQL Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on a dynamic query in BigQuery that will create x number of columns for each record that is passed through a json object. I have written the query to programmatically generate the query that will have x columns, but I don't know how to execute the generate query without copy and pasting it in the Editor. Is there a way to execute a query generated by another query?

I know it would be possible to generate the entire query in Python or any other programming language, but for this specific use case I would prefer to keep everything in SQL.

When I execute this query, it outputs the *generated query* below.

```
with names_ids as (
  SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_text, '$.name') as name,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_text, '$.id') as id
  FROM UNNEST([
    '{"id": "123456", "name": "test 1"}',
    '{"id": "789456", "name": "test 2"}',
    '{"id": "456123", "name": "test 3"}'
    ]) as json_text
)

select  
  concat(
    'select user_id, event_time, ',
    string_agg(
      concat(
      ' min(case when activity_id = ', json_extract(a.json_data, '$.id'), ' then 1 else end) as has_', lower(replace(json_extract_scalar(a.json_data, '$.name'), ' ', '_'))
      )
    )
  ) as query
  from (
    select to_json_string(a) as json_data
    from names_ids as a
    )
```

Output of above query:

```
select user_id, event_time,  min(case when activity_id = "123456" then 1 else end) as has_test_1, min(case when activity_id = "789456" then 1 else end) as has_test_2, min(case when activity_id = "456123" then 1 else end) as has_test_3
```

How do I execute the above query output?

Comment: Did you try create a function from the query creating dynamic query and take it from there

Comment: " ... but for this specific use case I would prefer to keep everything in SQL." No way as of today at least. You should either copy result and paste it into UI and run OR use client of your choice to "automate" process. As usually you can imagine that BigQuery Team will eventually come with some better option for you - but for this to happen you need to submit feature request - https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Comment: @TamirKlein I did try that, but found that STRING_AGG() can't be used inside of a UDF.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks for your feedback!